# How do I remove cat spray smell from the exterior of the house?

Tags: cleaning, pest

My in-laws have a cat problem.  The neighborhood cat is spraying the outside of their house and evidently it really stinks.  How can they get rid of the smell?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Short of industrial cleaners and Kilz Primer, I've not found a better product for dealing with organic compounds deposited by pets.

Comment: Are these enzyme type cleaners?  I haven't found anything that removes cat urine except tearing out carpet and pad, priming the subfloors and new carpets .  Hardwood is really a challenge.

Comment: i really missed the meaning of the question, they are talking outdoors. DUH!

Answer (score 1):

Vinegar and water should work, but really the source of the problem must be stopped.

You can try oranges, lemon, grapefruit (citrus) in the area to keep them away.  Also I suggest spay/nueter if it is the neighbors cat.  If it is feral, trapping is an option as well.

There are other ways which are more costly:

Motion Sensor + Sound

Motion Sensor + Water

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen Peroxide works vey well on odors like cat spray. Test in advance on an inconspicuous area to make sure it doesn't 'bleach' any surfaces.

Use the same kind you would use for first aide as if it was water, mixing in a bit of dish soap to remove the urine won't hurt either.